# programmatically autolayout UITableViewCell components

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an `UITableViewCell` and there are 2 UILabels in it as shown in the diagram below.

[image]

I want to programatically `autolayout` it so it fits the screen. How can i programatically add autolayout constraints ?

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

    if (self) 
    {
        self.mylabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 10, 100, 30)];
        self.mylabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:10.0f];
    }
}
```

nb: height of the cell is 400.

Comment: you want your label width to be equal to cell's width.  is it ? Or both height & width to be equal ?

Comment: I want it to be as the image shown above. Label 1 should be centered on the cell and width should be 100px. label 2 should be 75px and should be below the label 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement this code,

```
 #import "TableViewCell.h"

@implementation TableViewCell

- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    if (self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier])
    {
         _label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
         [_label1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
         [_label1 setText:@"Label 1"];
         [[self contentView] addSubview:_label1];

        _label2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 300, 50, 50)];
        [_label2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
        [_label2 setText:@"Label 2"];
        [[self contentView] addSubview:_label2];


        [self activateConstraint];
    }

return self ;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib {
// Initialization code

}

 - (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
[super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

// Configure the view for the selected state
}

 - (void)activateConstraint
 {
    [_label1 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [_label2 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];


//For Label1
NSLayoutConstraint *height1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_label1
                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                      toItem:nil
                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                  multiplier:1.0
                                                    constant:40];

NSLayoutConstraint *width1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_label1
                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                      toItem:nil
                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                  multiplier:1.0
                                                    constant:100];

NSLayoutConstraint *centerX1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_label1
                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                       toItem:self
                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                   multiplier:1.0
                                                     constant:0];

NSLayoutConstraint *centerY1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_label1
                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                       toItem:self
                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                   multiplier:1.0
                                                     constant:0];

[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:height1, width1, centerX1, centerY1, nil]] ;



    //For Label2
NSLayoutConstraint *height2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_label2
                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                       toItem:nil
                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                   multiplier:1.0
                                                     constant:40];

NSLayoutConstraint *width2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_label2
                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                       toItem:nil
                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                   multiplier:1.0
                                                     constant:75];

NSLayoutConstraint *topConstarint2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_label2
                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                       toItem:_label1
                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                   multiplier:1.0
                                                     constant:20];

NSLayoutConstraint *centerY2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_label2
                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                       toItem:self.contentView
                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                   multiplier:1.0
                                                     constant:0];


[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: height2, width2, topConstarint2, centerY2, nil]] ;
 }

 @end
```

Comment: sorry i want to do this programatically

Comment: Give me few minutes. I will do that for you.

Comment: Thanks, i am waiting for your reply.

Comment: @JitendraGandhi please format the code in your answer and not link to a download. Links will go dead or be moved and then nobody else will be able to use this answer

Comment: My UILabel is created programatically. If so how can i refer it from the `activateConstraint ` method ?

Comment: 'activateConstraint' is a self made method. It can refer your golbally decalred instances.

Comment: Why is `[_label1 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];` set to NO. It should be YES i think ?

Comment: It must be set to NO, whenever you are adding any constraint programmatically.

Comment: Anyway, the labels are not displaying. Can i have the downloadable code ?

Comment: Give me few minutes, please.

Comment: Here is all what you need : https://www.dropbox.com/sh/e2gydzgzoxgighs/AADkOp03p9w_a85jxINTQnzRa?dl=0

Dont forget to accept my answer :)